# dex2jar is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, android, apk, dex2jar

I am trying to convert one of my old APK's to a jar. 
1. I downloaded apk tool in order to get the classes.dex file from my apk.
2. I downloaded dex2 jar and in the command line entered:

```
C:\Users\myLaptop\Downloads\dex2jar-2.0>dex2jar classes.dex
```

This lead to this Error:

```
dex2jar is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I am using a windows machine. I saw other questions posted on the issue on this site, when I tried them they didn't work. One solution was to use dex2jar version 0.0.9.15, but I got the same error when attempting to use that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. If anyone is using dex2jar version 2.0 or higher, use this command in windows:

```
C:\Users\Zookeeper\Downloads\dex2jar-2.0>d2j-dex2jar classes.dex dex2jar classes.dex ->.\classes-dex2jar.jar
```

I now have a jar file from my apk

Answer (score 0):

If the above solution doesn't work, try this:

1. Copy your .apk file into the dex2jar folder.
2. Open terminal/cmd in that folder.
3. Enter this command `d2j-dex2jar.bat nameOfYourApkFile.apk`

This way you will get a .jar file generated from the .apk file in that folder.